# Shiny for R - conditional comparing text input

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to take input from a dropdown, and displaying a string depending on the selection

in ui.R:

```
selectInput(inputId = "engine",
          label = h3("Select Search Engine"),
          choices = c("Bing", "Google"),
          selected = "Bing"))
```

in server.R:

```
   if ( input$engine == "Bing"){

    output$value <- renderText({ input$engine })
}
```

This works fine when the if statement is set to something trivial like  1 == 1 and outputs the text string, but not when I try to check the actual input (the if statement doesn't trigger). Seems like it should be something easy but I've been stuck on this for a while now....what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try putting the if statement inside renderText. This would then return input$engine if input$engine == 'Bing'

Comment: Can you specify what portion needs to go inside renderText? I tried putting renderText around the entire if statement, just the  input$engine inside the if statement and a few other ways with no luck...

Comment: If you put a mini-example together in one file (see tutorial [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/single-file.html)) I will take a look.

Comment: Here you go:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t0s2s8i0s3v9o1v/stack.txt?dl=0

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you would want that if statement here but this works:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$value <- renderText({
      if ( input$engine == "Bing") {
        ret <- paste0("https://", input$text, "/?pid=", input$engine,"+{adgroupname}+{keyword}+{matchtype}+{adposition}")
      } else {
        ret <- paste0("https://", input$text, "/?pid=", input$engine,"+{adgroupname}+{keyword}+{matchtype}+{adposition}")
      }

      ret
    })
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           selectInput(inputId = "engine",
                       label = h3("Select Search Engine"),
                       choices = c("Bing", "Google"),
                       selected = "Bing")),
    column(3,
           textInput("text", label = h3("URL"), value = "www.test.com"))),

  hr(),
  h3("Final Url:"),
  fluidRow(column(9, h4(textOutput("value"), style = "color:blue")))

))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```